# Div onclick inner content not clickable?

Tags: html, jquery, css, onclick

When I click on div-two I want to show div-2. I'm using Jquery index and it works but when I put other content/html inside the on-click div it always shows div-1 regardless of what button is clicked. On the following fiddle example if you click the **green** inner div you'll see the results.

I'm assuming this is an index or propagation issue, can this be corrected or am I pushing the limits of the function?

https://jsfiddle.net/1e230w8s/

```js
// Matches and shows Butts to index order.
let $games = $('.game');

$('.butts').on('click', e => {
  let $target = $games.eq($(e.target).index()).show();  
  $games.not($target).hide();
});

// Finds all Butts and calls `sumBoxes` onclick
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("butts");
for (let butts of boxes){ butts.addEventListener("click", sumBoxes); }

// sumBox Calculates each visible Box 
function sumBoxes(event) {
  var total = 0;
  $('.box:visible').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text());
  });
  $('.sum').html("Total : " + total); // Replaces contents of `.sum`
}
```

```css
body {background: #eeeeee;}

.game {display:none;}

.box {float: left;font: bold 17px arial;text-align: center;margin: 10px 10px 20px 0;padding: 10px 25.54px;background: #fff;color: blue}

.butts {cursor:pointer; width:200px;height:40px;background:#fff; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right:10px; float:left;border:1px solid blue;}

.sum {clear:both;margin-top:40px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="float: left;width: 100%;">
   <div class="butts">1 <div style="float:right;width:40px;height:20px;background:lightgreen;">1</div></div>
   <div class="butts">2 <div style="float:right;width:40px;height:20px;background:lightgreen;">2</div></div>
   <div class="butts">3 <div style="float:right;width:40px;height:20px;background:lightgreen;">3</div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
   <div class="game">
     <div class="box">1 Box</div>
   </div>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="box">2 Box</div>
  </div>
    <div class="game">
    <div class="box">3 Box</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sum"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code you have use `e.target` so when you click on children div current target will be inner div tag and according to your code its value will be `0` that's why only first one is showing .Instead you can check if the `e.target` has `butts` class or not depending on this change your selector.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
// Matches and shows Butts to index order.
let $games = $('.game');

$('.butts').on('click', e => {
  //check is target has class .butts 
  var target = $(e.target).hasClass("butts") ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest(".butts")
 let $target = $games.eq(target.index()).show();
  $games.not($target).hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.game {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  font: bold 17px arial;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 10px 20px 0;
  padding: 10px 25.54px;
  background: #fff;
  color: blue
}

.butts {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.sum {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="float: left;width: 100%;">
  <div class="butts">1
    <div style="float:right;width:40px;height:20px;background:lightgreen;">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="butts">2
    <div style="float:right;width:40px;height:20px;background:lightgreen;">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="butts">3
    <div style="float:right;width:40px;height:20px;background:lightgreen;">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="game">
    <div class="box">1 Box</div>
  </div>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="box">2 Box</div>
  </div>
  <div class="game">
    <div class="box">3 Box</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sum"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Swati. I'm still learning, I noticed you used **var**, is this better than **let**?

Comment: Hi, that depends on you .But, i would suggest you to look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) post will help you to understand difference between both .